# Joomla Empty Character

Tags: joomla, character

I'd like to know if there's a character that appears invisible in the frontpage of our website but Joomla recognizes it.

I ask this because, many of you know, that you always have to write something in a brief description, but you want it to have nothing on the frontpage so it can look better.
Hence why I'm asking if there's such char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try &nbsp; or &#160; thats is the same char but different syntax